# React js how to axios post from outside of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a function that will handle getting data to and from a server. This function takes the url to contact and uses the token to authorize itself against the server. This function is quite long. I would therefore want every other page in my react app to call this function with the needed url and then let this function handle everything else. I therefore need each page to await this function but I get "Error: Invalid hook call" no matter what I try.

This is the function that handles post requests to the server:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createRef, lazy, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";

import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import axios from "axios";

export async function getProtectedAsset(url) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  //If we do not have a token
  if (user["userID"] == -1) {
    return "Error: No token";
  } else {
    try {
      //Get user data
      const token = {
        accessToken: user["accessToken"],
        email: user["email"],
        userID: user["userID"],
      };

      //Check if accessToken is about to expire (60s mairgain)
      if (
        Date.now() >=
        jwt_decode(token["accessToken"])["exp"] * 1000 - 60000
      ) {
        //Get new token
        const res = await axios
          .post("http://127.0.0.1:5002/refreshtoken", {
            token: user["refreshToken"],
          })
          .then((res) => {
            setUser({
              userID: user["userID"],
              email: user["email"],
              accessToken: res.data["accessToken"],
              refreshToken: user["refreshToken"],
              accountType: user["accountType"],
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      }
      //Our token is fresh
      else {
        const res = await axios
          .post(url, token)
          .then((promise) => {
            return promise.data;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the page/component that I try to call this function from:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

import { UserContext } from "../../UserContext";

import { getProtectedAsset } from "../../getProtectedAsset";

const Settings = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      let data = await getProtectedAsset("http://127.0.0.1:5002/mypage");
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }, []);


  return <></>;
};

export default Settings;
```

This gives me the error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

I have tried everything I can imagine and read different tutorials/guides/docs but still cannot figure out the problem. Usually it is the lack of knowledge, or some thinking mistakes, but I really need help with this one!

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are using `useContext()` hook inside `getProtectedAsset()` function.
Instead of using useContext inside getProtectedAsset try to pass `user` as parameter like `url` to the function.

```
let data = await getProtectedAsset(url, user);
```